# Win11: VSCode disappeared, and all attempts to reinstall hang on "setup is preparing to install visual studio code"

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, installation

**VSCode is gone and I'm unable to reinstall it on Win11.**

Symptoms are identical to this closed issue from 2018:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/43949

**History:**
VSCode was running happily on my Win11 laptop (user install) for at least six months. I used it every day. On October 2 (I think) it disappeared - no longer in programs/features, and the shortcut changed to a missing file. I can only presume Code self-updated and committed suicide? I've always let it run updates when they're available. The only Windows update that happened that day or even near it is PowerShell v7.3.7.

All attempts at vscode reinstallation have failed and result only in a dialog box that says "Setup is preparing to install Visual Studio Code on your computer". Task manager displays a 32-bit installer running although I'm using x64.

[Screenshot of lying dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TifiH.png)

[Screenshot of task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6aTk.png)

Most times I can't even end the dialog box without killing the process; the cancel button doesn't respond, nor does the x. The event logs don't mention code at all except when I force quit the setup:

```
The program VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.83.0.tmp version 51.1052.0.0 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available, check the problem history in the Security and Maintenance control panel.
 Process ID: 6588
 Start Time: 01d9fc947889a218
 Termination Time: 4294967295
 Application Path: C:\Users\JBLOGGS\AppData\Local\Temp\is-DNV0F.tmp\VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.83.0.tmp
 Report Id: 39830549-0ada-4c69-b079-db7308816e4b
 Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID: 
 Hang type: Top level window is idle
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

- reinstalling using winget, with and without quiet flags and verbose logging
- manually running uninstall from the programdata\username path (this ran without error)
- manual download/install of user setup executable
- manual download/install of system setup/all users executable
- swearing at my computer
- combing through registry HKLM to find & remove all shards of vscode
- trying to interpret what I see in ProcessMonitor (no clue)
- trying more colorful swear words

This issue is 10000% repeatable. Nothing else seems amiss.

I've temporarily disabled the security tools I can disable, although I can't touch some (crowdstrike) and am not going to mess around with that or I'll make powerful enemies. Anyway, I installed Code for the first time with all these tools running, and I can currently install / update other things without issues.

Advice? My appdata\username\roaming\code folder is still intact, but there's nothing new in the logs since this happened. I sync my settings so I'm not worried about losing that so much - I just want the application back.

I would like to find the installation/error logs (if they've even been generated) if someone can help me find them.

Comment: note: Oct 2 is the release date of [1.82.3](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases/tag/1.82.3), but too early to be related to [1.83.0](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/releases/tag/1.83.0).

Comment: "_Task manager displays a 32-bit installer running although I'm using x64_" what do you mean by "using x64"? You mean you installed the 64-bit installer? Exactly which installation method did you choose? For what processor architecture? User setup or system setup? (I see user, but have you tried system?) And what privileges does your user on this machine have? Admin?

Comment: I'm suspicious of the security tool you won't disable (crowdstrike). Are you allowed to change any of its configuration? Is there a way to make it ignore the VS Code installer? Can you reproduce this issue on another machine with the same security tool active?

Comment: what if you just backup the contents of the `User` subdirectory of `appdata\username\roaming\code` and then nuke it along with wherever VS Code is installed in `Program Files`? And what version of VS Code was installed before it "died"?

Comment: Thanks - @starball ...in order:
- 1. ? Trying to get the latest version. Have been up to date til Oct 2nd. I keep current whenever there's an update; never failed until now. 
- Using x64 installer every time I've run executable. (See winget screenshot; it's trying!) Tried both user and system setup; am a local admin.
- 3. I WFH & have no other computers to test on. Can't disable crowdstrike w/o surgery that will trigger cybersecurity alerts.
- 4. No code executable exists in program files, nor in appdata. Just settings.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me.

This is how I solved it, hope it helps!

```
runas /machine:x86 /trustlevel:0x20000 .\VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.69.2.exe
```

Comment: mind explaining what trust level 0x20000 is and what the risks are?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20218503/22791048

Comment: Hi @cammart .... thanks for your help. I can't get it to run with the /machine:x86 switch; it just keeps returning me to runas help. 
When I remove that and just specify the trustlevel, the installer launches, walks me through the settings options (I left at default), then gets to the same point where it just sits there, stuck - I have to force end the process. 
I've verified I can install the same executable on a Win2019 vm, and on a Win10 VDI.
I've verified I can run/install other applications (exes and msis) on THIS system.
It's something unique to vscode + this laptop and GRRRRRRR :)

Comment: Hi @Alstromeria, before executing that command I completely uninstall VS Code: 


Deleted directory C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Code

Deleted directory C:\Users\xxxx\.vscode

I guess you already did all of these things, but better to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue exactly and work around here not work.
I downloaded and unzipped the vscode then added its bin path: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/324197/unable-to-install-visual-studio-code-editor

Comment: and that worked for you?